# How to preg_match special chars: open, closed double quotes (hex 93, 94)

Tags: php, unicode, preg-match, ascii, special-characters

I want to PHP preg_match 'very specific' characters from a string.  The characters are the 'special' open-double-quotes, and closed-double-quotes, hex 93 and hex 94. How do I do this?

Comment: You're not likely to get help unless you provide more details. Sample input, sample output, your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

As you can find on the PHP manual [here](http://www.php.net//manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) you can use the escape sequence

```
\xhh
```

Where hh is the hex code.

So here is an example of finding a quoted sentence:

```
$pattern = '/[\x93\x94]?.*[\x93\x94]?/';
if(preg_match($pattern, "\"Hello\"")){
 echo "Goal!!";
}
```

The previous code should echo "Goal!!"

Cheers

---

You could also use the characters themselves for an easy solution

```
    $pattern = '/[""].*[""]/';
    if(preg_match($pattern, "\"Hello\"")){
     echo "Goal!!";
    }
```